# Access an S3 bucket from ColdFusion

Tags: amazon-s3, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

This is my first time using S3 buckets and I have pulled out every hair on my head at this point.

I have set up an S3 bucket, created a pair of keys with "Identity and Access Management", I have given the user access to the bucket, but I just can't read anything. I have tested the access with CyberDuck and it works so the issue is not one of permissions.

I am trying

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="s3://#accessKey#:#secretKey#@bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/" name="dirData">
```

and

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="s3://#accessKey#:#secretKey#@s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/" name="dirData">
```

and in both cases get a similar error. `The cause of this exception was: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of "s3://*******:*******@s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName" because it is not a folder..`

I have also tried

```
<cffile action="read" file="s3://#accessKey#:#secretKey#@s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/test.txt" variable="fileData" />
```

and get the error `The cause of this exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3://*******:@s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/test.txt.`

Does anyone have any idea how I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong path. Try the following. For file and directory tags/functions you need to use the path like this.

```
s3://#accessKey#:#secretKey#@bucketName/test.txt
```

```
<cffile action="read" file="s3://#accessKey#:#secretKey#@bucketName/test.txt" variable="fileData" />
```

Comment: If I do as you suggest and leave the server name out or the request I now get the error `The cause of this exception was: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Unknown message with code "S3 Error Message."..` which isn't all that helpful, any other ideas? @rrk

Comment: @Jay2001, I know this way too late. This is probably a permission issue. But I think the GetBucketLocation permission needs to be there for user which accesskey and secret is generated(inaddition to GetObject).

Answer (score 0):

just to expand on the error message that I think @Jay2001 is getting. Heres an extract from the error I get when running the same code

The cause of this exception was: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Unknown message with code "S3 Error Message."..

Caused by: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 Error Message. GET '/' on Host 's3.amazonaws.com' @ 'Thu, 29 Jun 2023 11:45:14 GMT' -- ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: `AccessDenied`Access Deniedxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getBucket(S3Service.java:1911)
at coldfusion.vfs.s3.S3FileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(S3FileProvider.java:95)
... 49 more

Im investigating the permissions mentioned by @rrk to see if theyre linked with the keys Ive been given to use by our devops

UPDATE So our devops sorted the permissions out and I then got the error :

`InvalidRequest`The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

and this is where my version of ACF 10 was too old. In ACF10 the file tags use v2 signatures and my S3 buckets which are pretty new wanted v4 signatures, hence the error message.

Thanks to @Brian and his info he added to this question :
[Amazon s3 Region - coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101755/amazon-s3-region-coldfusion/55114392#55114392)

Now luckily we are in the process of upgrading ACF so im hoping this problem will go away when thats complete

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34617416)